# How can I get Swift to specialize this function for arrays?

Tags: swift, generics, decodable

I have a function, in conformance with `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol`, that is roughly:

```
func decode<T : Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> T {
  return type.init(from: decoder)
}
```

However, if `T` is an `Array`, then its init method is unnecessarily slow (and yes, I have benchmarked and it makes a big difference). So for arrays, I want to run something like:

```
func decode<U : Decodable>(_ type: [U].Type, forKey key: K) throws -> [U] {
  var array: [U] = []
  for ... {
    array.append(U.ElementType.init(from: decoder))
  }
  return array
}
```

However, as it currently is, only the first function is ever called, even for arrays. I'd also be fine doing something like `if let arrayType = type as? [Decodable] {...}` or any other sort of branching where I can run specific code. Crazy hacks are fine if necessary.

Is there an easy way to do this? It would be a big performance win for me.

Comment: Your calling code also needs to be generic in the same way. The compiler needs to be able to determine all these types are runtime, not compile time. It will be specialize to the most strict version that it can prove, but it will not change its mind at runtime. What does your calling code (the code that calls `decode`) look like?

Comment: The calling code is in `init(from: Decoder)`, which I don't have any control over, and which is most often auto-generated.

Comment: I've built some examples of what I think you're writing, and I can't reproduce this. Do you have a simplified version that demonstrates the problem? `KeyedDecodingContainer` isn't a protocol, so I'm trying to work out what you mean by "in conformance with."

Comment: Good catch, I meant KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol. Here's the code I have: https://gist.github.com/michaeleisel/bcd7ff62c62aec8e82bbb5a61f6dd500

Comment: (there are build errors, but that's because I'm just messing with it right now. And the errors will point you to the key places!)

Comment: The key area is around line 932, but you can also get this going in a larger project if you pull the ZippyJSON pod and replace ZippyJSONDecoder.swift with that gist